# window.location.href in IE not properly working

Tags: internet-explorer-8, window.location

I have a problem when using window.location.href. It works fine in IE9 and IE10. But when I test it in IE8, it redirects me to another page. It suppose to download a file. Please help me with this one. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "key:" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "window.location.replace('Document.aspx?table=TV_IMAGES');", true);
```

I also tried using window.location, document.location, making it a function and using session time out. But none of these work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just Use `window.location = 'http://demo.org/#anchor';`
Change up to your requirements..Hope this will Help you out

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Window.location.href= 'Document.aspx?table=TV_IMAGES'
```

instead of replace function